# Redirect to another webpage in jQuery via button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I'm using Jade and my HTML template looks something like this

```
.container
        .row
          form
            .span3.input-append(style='margin-top: 30%; margin-left: 30%;')
              input#main_search.span2(style='height: 26px; width: 400px;', type='text', id='searchBox' )
              input.btn.btn-large.btn-primary(type='button', value='search', id='searchButton')
include partials/scripts
```

And my scripts.jade includes a bunch of Javascript functions including

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('foo');
    $("searchButton").click(function() {
        console.log('sup');
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    });
});
```

Console output -

```
foo
```

Answer (score 5):

Change `searchButton` to `#searchButton`. It's an ID, so must be prefixed with `#`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `#` in the **[id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)**. it should be `#searchButton` instead of `searchButton`

```
 $("#searchButton").click(function() {
        console.log('sup');
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    });
```

Also not that even you have incorrect selector `$("searchButton")` which does not find any elements jquery will not throw any error while registering the click handler on them unlike `document.getElementById` where the result will be undefined and accessing the properties will throw an error.